# JDK 8 installation does not progress on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, java, jdk

I downloaded <strike>`jre-8u91-windows-x64.tar.gz`</strike> `jdk-8u91-windows-x64.exe` from <strike>Oracle web site</strike>

[this Oracle web site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). When I open it (by clicking double) installation windows open, then I click **Next** and there is a windows which shows the installation progress. But that is **not processing.** It is **still 0** for nearly 20 minutes. My friends installed it in several minutes.

[image]

I have **64-bit Windows 10** OS. I have no idea about the reason.

Comment: One weirdness: You say the file is named **`jre`** `-8u91-windows-x64.tar.gz`, but the installation window in the picture says "Java Se **Development Kit**". The *Development Kit* installation file should be something with `jdk` in its name, not `jre`. Maybe you have got the wrong file?

Comment: Actually I have `jdk-8u91-windows-x64.exe` in my Downloads folder. And I am trying to run that file. I think I gave you wrong link and name. Eclipse Java FX said that I need Java 8 and I downloaded jdk8 but as I said installation does not progress

Comment: I was able to install that specific version of the JDK 8  without a problem on my Windows 10 machine.  Are you attempting to install it as a `User` or as an `Administrator`?

Comment: I am installing as an Administrator. But now I tried to run as administrator and it fixed. Thanks

Comment: I had the same issue and it seems to have been related to having a java process open (I had gogland running), after closing that process the installer immediately completed.

Answer (score 3):

In my case there's a Java process running (JDK 7). I just terminated that process and Java installer completed installation. In order to do it follow these steps.

1. Open task manager.
2. Find-out Java SE Binary process running.
3. Right click on it and end task or use  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>E</kbd>
4. Now Java installer completes installation.

Hope it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I *thought* I had this problem, and actually, there was a window that had popped up on another screen that required me to hit "next". If anyone else is having this issue I'd check to make sure that there isn't a popup behind one of your other windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, when I cancel the installation, it turned out that it had been successfully installed on my machine and it was only the progress bar that hanged.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I found that my file had been "blocked" because it was downloaded.

- Locate the file in your downloads folder.
- Right-Click on Properties.
- Press the 'UnBlock' button on the General tab.

Note: if your file was not blocked there will be no 'UnBlock' button.

I also ran as Administrator.

It still took forever to start (more than 10 minutes, so I went away and worked on something else).

Regarding Shashant's answer, the two JDK processes didn't seem to have any effect, but mine were jdk-8 and not jdk-7.  They seemed to pop up as soon as I started the installer.